# how to fix this error "Trying to access array offset on value of type null"

Tags: php

the message:
Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple\individu_keputusan.php on line 48

my coding:

```html
$papar=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT* FROM peserta
WHERE idpeserta='$PESERTA'");
$info1=mysqli_fetch_array($papar);
#PANGGIL REKOD PEMENANG IKUT ID PESERTA
$WINNER=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *
FROM pemenang WHERE idpeserta='$PESERTA'");
$win=mysqli_fetch_array ($WINNER); 

#if($win==NULL){
echo "<script>alert('Dukacita dimaklumkan anda tidak 
memenangi pertandingan ini');
window.location='dashboard.php'</script>";
}
?>
<html>
<center>
<div><h2>DASHBOARD PESERTA</h2></div>
<table width="80%" border=0 align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="5" valign="middle" align="right"><b>
<a href="dashboard.php">HOME</a> |
<a href="logout.php">KELUAR</a></b></td>
</tr>
<tr><td  colspan="5">
<hr>
NAMA: <?php echo $info1['nama'];?><br>
NOM.KP: <?php echo $info1['idpeserta'];?><br>
NOM.HP: <?php echo $info1['nomhp'];?><br>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5"><hr><td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5">
KEPUTUSAN RASMI <?php echo $kata1;?><br>
TEMPAT: <?php echo $win['tempat'];?><br>
<hr>
</center>
</html>
```

---

line 48 : `TEMPAT: <?php echo $win['tempat'];?><br>`

ive tried using isset and the error did go away but it just removed the message not actually "fix" it to work. HELPPP

Comment: Add code as text not as image

Comment: Also a little discovery .. Do a `print_r( $win );` -- Your errors is telling you that `tempat` is null or doesn't exist.

Comment: You should exit the script in the `if ($win == NULL)` block, so you don't try to access the nonexistent `$win['tempat']`

Answer (score 0):

PHP keeps executing after the **window.location**, so you need to exit after it.  At the moment, it keeps executing even though WIN is null.

```php
$papar=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT* FROM peserta
WHERE idpeserta='$PESERTA'");
$info1=mysqli_fetch_array($papar);
#PANGGIL REKOD PEMENANG IKUT ID PESERTA
$WINNER=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *
FROM pemenang WHERE idpeserta='$PESERTA'");
$win=mysqli_fetch_array ($WINNER); 

#if($win==NULL){
echo "<script>alert('Dukacita dimaklumkan anda tidak 
memenangi pertandingan ini');
window.location='dashboard.php'</script>";
exit;  //<---------------------------
}
?>
<html>
<center>
<div><h2>DASHBOARD PESERTA</h2></div>
<table width="80%" border=0 align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="5" valign="middle" align="right"><b>
<a href="dashboard.php">HOME</a> |
<a href="logout.php">KELUAR</a></b></td>
</tr>
<tr><td  colspan="5">
<hr>
NAMA: <?php echo $info1['nama'];?><br>
NOM.KP: <?php echo $info1['idpeserta'];?><br>
NOM.HP: <?php echo $info1['nomhp'];?><br>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5"><hr><td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5">
KEPUTUSAN RASMI <?php echo $kata1;?><br>
TEMPAT: <?php echo $win['tempat'];?><br>
<hr>
</center>
</html>
```